# find out what is inside a function

Tags: actionscript-3

For example, there is a function like this:

```
function a(){
    if(stage.color==0xffffff){
        trace("The color of stage is White");
    }
}
```

now, is it possible to get a String, XML or anything containing :

```
//these are the codes inside function "a"
if(stage.color==0xffffff){
    trace("The color of stage is White");
}
```

to see what does a function do?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that's not possible, but why you need that ?

Comment: Do you always ask people why they want their answer? :)

Comment: If you want to do this at runtime then you should have known already that a compiled language does not contain lines of code that can be read which should already answer your question. If this is not for runtime then read those as file like any other text files. Either way the question has no answer since it cannot apply to compiled language like AS3.

Comment: If the question is like yours, YES, I ask them ! May be we can find another approach to resolve the original problem ! And, as you know, I'm not paid to answer the questions of others, I try just to help.

Comment: Thanks for your trying to help. I want to load SWFs and see what is in it's functions. please don't ask how to get function names and things like this.

Comment: The question is only asked because the PO doesn't understand the technology. Lines of code cannot be read at runtime in compiled languages. Question is pointless and voted down.

Comment: Do you understand what a compiled language is?

Comment: I'm about 15 years old. so I should not know "anything". I know as much as my age.

Comment: then I will post an answer for you.

Comment: Guys, if they are not possible, so how decompilers work? so that should be possible to convert the compiled content to actionscript codes.and I know about compiling. don't think of me as an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Reading lines of code at runtime is not possible with compiled languages like Flash technology. With this technology (like many others) you write a code using a language (AS3 for example) in what is very much like text files. Then to complete the process and generate a runnable file (.swf) you have to compile everything. During that compilation those text files full of code are converted to machine readable instructions. That means that the lines of code no longer exist and are converted to something else. So the simple answer to your question is that no it's not possible, the correct answer is that the question doesn't apply. A language like Javascript for example would be a candidate for that question since that code is not compiled.

Comment: I understand these things .can't reconvert the "converted to something else" codes to the actionscript code? like what decompilers do

Comment: and something else.if I accept your answer, will you remove your votedown? :)

Comment: With most technology you can rebuild back (more or less efficiently and accurately) the original files but not at runtime. Edit your question to include that you are new to this technology and I'll remove my vote.

Comment: I think you are right.that's not possible at runtime.(but I'm not sure.that may be possible).and I'm young but not new to technology.